# Issue with timestamp in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code which i use to compare a timestamp field with a date i've selected before!
But i get an error in syntax..
Howcome?

```
$query = sprintf( 'SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE date("Y-m-d", "time") = $date' );
```

The error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' "time") = $date' at line 1
```

While, i'm comparing a timestamp which is the field time, and a date which is `$date`
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Post the error. Also provide more information about how/why you are comparing these fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time` should not be quoted as it is a field reference, not a [string literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM coupon WHERE DATE(time) = $date');
```

**Note:** You are susceptible to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: I still get this error though...
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' time) = $date' at line 1

Comment: Thanks, i guess it works, but, does it makes sense for it to tell me this now? Unknown column '$date' in 'where clause'

Comment: I solved it by changing single to double quotes :) thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you will need to quote a literal date. I encourage you to read the string literal link I provide in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up the PHP function

```
date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

and the MySQL function.

```
DATE( expr )
```

See the manual entries respectively:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date